# Trouble selecting a classname with waitForSelector in Playwright

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, playwright

I am scraping a page and this is the data I'm looking for:

```
<div class="account-balance">
<span class="name">Total balance</span>
<span class="balance">$10</span>
</div>
```

If I look for the text "total balance," I can find it:

```
await page.waitForSelector('text=Total balance');
```

But if I try to find a classname, it times out:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.account-balance');
```

I've tried waitForSelector as well as locator, and whenever I target a classname like this, it fails. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There may be possibility that there are multiple class with same value. You can try with xpath.

```
await page.waitForSelector(xpath=//div[@class='account-balance']);
```

Or

```
await page.waitForSelector(xpath=//span[text()='Total balance']/..);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the class name for the text `Total balance` and then wait for it.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.account-balance > .name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a selector engine (like text or css), try using this

```
span:has-text('Total balance');
```

Also, check if there are multiple text with `Total balance`. In that case, you case use the `nth` matcher to select the text - for e.g. you can use this locator to select the 3rd instance of `Total balance`

```
await page.locator(':nth-match(:text("Total balance"), 3)').click();
```